# UIViewController doesn't update view's constraints when the device orientation is changing

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, orientation

I'm making an app where the iPad can be used in both landscape and portrait mode. 
The configuration of my UIViewControllers is the following :

I have a `UIViewController` with a `UICollectionView` which has the following constraints : **top, leading, trailing, and bottom** set to **0** with its superview (the superview is the `UIView` of my `UIViewController`).

When I tap a cell, I push another `UIViewController` in the `UINavigationController` which is a detail viewController of the cell. Simple.

When I change the device orientation in the **first** view controller, the `UICollectionView` bounds are set properly.

Here come my **problem** :

If I select a cell in the `UICollectionView`, the second detail viewController is displayed. Then if in this second ViewController I change the device orientation and then I go back into the first viewController, the  view of my `UIViewController` hasn't been rotated. I don't know why, I tried this without success :

`self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` in `viewDidAppear()` of my firstViewController to update constraints according the current orientation, it didn't work. This didn't work because I noticed one thing :

The frame view of my first viewController is still the same as the previous orientation, it didn't change... But if I rotate again the device, the `UIViewController` detect the orientation changes, and the view bounds are set properly.

So my problem is : when I'm in the second view controller, and that I'm rotating the device, and then that I go back in the previous view controller, the previous controller hasn't detected the orientation change I just made in the second view controller.

GIF Demo :

[image]

After that I made a rotation from portrait to landscape mode, the **view** **is not** changed as the debug view hierarchy tool shows below :

[image]

The `UIView` is still in portrait, so the `UICollectionView` constraint's can't be updated with the new orientation...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Resolved by resetting the frame of the view in my first viewController with the screen bounds in the `viewWillAppear` method :

```
public override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    self.view.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Like that the main UIView of my viewController have the right frame, and the constraints can be updated automatically when I call `layoutIfNeeded()` on my UIView.

Answer (score 0):

Found need to reset the frame size of collectionview. add self.collectionview.frame.size = size

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

    if let layout = self.collectionview.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        let width = (size.width - 30) / 3
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width:width, height:width)
        self.collectionview.frame.size = size
        layout.invalidateLayout()
    }
}
```